# How to get the response stream of browser in Java WebDriver program

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver, htmlunit, selenium-webdriver

I need to validate the PDF report. I need to get the report embeded in HTML. If I read that URL using:

`File file = new File("url");`

or

`HttpWebConnection.getResponse();`

it requests the URL in separate session, hence it cannot get the file.

Does ieDriver have something like HtmlUnit?

`HttpWebConnection.getResponse()`

or somebody can suggest alternative.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately it does not.
If you want to get the response code you will need a proxy. If you are using Java then [Browser Mob](http://opensource.webmetrics.com/browsermob-proxy/) is what you need. You may also try making XmlHttpRequest from javascript and get the status code in that way.
You could also stick to the method you are using right now (separate request from Java) but pass the cookie with session (you can obtain the cookie from WebDriver)